# Где храняться в базе данных информация о подписках в woocomerce subscription?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Дело в том, что в документации указано

```
данные о подписках будут храниться в таблице shop_subscription (или wp_shop_subscription, в зависимости от префикса таблиц в вашей базе данных).
```

Но у меня да же нет таблиц с subscription
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно подключиться к бд и получать данные на прямую из базы данных, но найти где лежат пользователи и подписки пользователей я не могу, буду рад помощи, спасибо.

```
Woocomerce 7.9.0
woocomerce subscription 5.2.0
```

Comment: Не лезь напрямую в базу. Для доступа из сторонних приложений есть REST-API. Изнутри - родные функции, а в крайнем случае [wpdb](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wpdb)

Comment: @SeVlad Пытался я уже реализовать через RestApi, то ли не через тот реализовывал т.к. пользователя я мог получить только того которого указал и только одного, так же мне нужно получить из этого всего ссылку на аватар пользователя, его количество подписок и в подписках надо добавить ещё 1 колнку с сирийным номером, на сколько я понял wpdb работает на прямую из html, но я пишу отдельный сервер на C# который будет делать запрос к бд, как то так. Мне нужна эта база данных

Comment: Мне трудно понять что ты написал, но в прошлом вопросе я тебе давал правильную ссылку. Нужно делать как нужно, а не как вздумается.

Comment: `на сколько я понял wpdb работает на прямую из html` -- что? Вам никто не запрещает создавать свои эндпойнты и прокручивать там нужную Вам логику. `в подписках надо добавить ещё 1 колнку с сирийным номером` -- менять исходные таблицы, весьма плохая идея, в зависимости от того как хранится подписка, могут быть различные варианты хранения Вашего серийного номера.

Comment: @Simon Привязку к железу я могу сохранять и в другой базе данных включая так же таблицу, если изначально соберу данные из 1 нормально